# pop out edit fields webbrowser delphi

Tags: delphi, browser

I want to do something that seems very simple but in code I think it is going to be more difficult.

Imagine a webbrowser with any random website(has a few edit fields). Now I want to place a button somewhere on this application outside of the webbrowser. When I click this I want the webbrowser to go slightly grey seethrough ( you can still read the webpage, just a little darker) But I want the edit fields to stay blank, white. This way they 'pop out'.

is this possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought that pops up into my mind: you could inject a `<div>` that would do the grey see-through and enumerate the edit-boxes so their z-index is so only they are above this new div.

Enumerating the edit-boxes should be possible with the elements collection of root document or the forms from the forms collection.

Comment: +1, all that is doable through DOM interfaces of the document. Assuming embedded webbrowser, which is not clear from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a realistic proposal. To have any real chance of doing this you'd need to get inside the implementation of the renderer. For that I think you'd need to start with a browser engine whose source you could modify, e.g. Webkit or Gecko.